# How can I magnify, intensify, and redirect the light from a skylight so that it is most effective?

Tags: lighting, interior

My condo has a skylight about 6 feet above the interior ceiling. How can I magnify, intensify, and redirect the light so that it is most effective?

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the concept of a sun tube, a mirrored tube that runs from the roof to a room.  If the walls of the alcove that houses the skylight are not already white, paint them white.  It will reflect more light than a darker color.  If you really want as much light from the skylight as possible, mount mirrors on the walls of the skylight.

Comment: I have used aluminum foil to reflect light in this way. It may not be pretty when applied, it won't be easy to do either.

Comment: @Jack - you can find [foil covered board or paper](http://www.grafixarts.com/product/metallic_foil_board_paper-2) at many craft and art stores - that might be easier to install and keep flat.